# Center relative element

Tags: css

I have an relative button

```
button {
    width: 305.4px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #E43B40;
    margin-top: 109.5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Roboto Bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative
}
```

I am trying to center it in the middle of screen. But it is stuck on the same place , the margins does not affect it. Parent element of this button is div with styles as follows:

```
parent {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin-top: 504px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
     padding-bottom: 250px;
     overflow: auto;
     display: block;
}
```

What could possibly cause this? Demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jxgmabyz/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.button {
    width: 305.4px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #E43B40;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Roboto Bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.parent{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
     text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <button class="button" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That `translateY` is so awesome, never seen that before! Great answer! This is supported from IE10, flexbox IE11 => this is a better answer for vertical alignment then most out there!

Comment: the text align center does the trick , but there are more element in container that shouldnt be centered with this text align

Comment: @Joshmorning please provide html so that i can update my answer more precisely

Answer (score 0):

```
button {
    width: 305.4px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #E43B40;
    margin-top: 109.5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Roboto Bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
}
parent{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 504px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 padding-bottom: 250px;
 overflow: auto;
 display: block;
 text-align:center;
}
```

i have updated both classes. apply it in your css.